# How do I decompress a rar archive that does not consist of one file in the linux console?

Tags: linux, rar, unrar

I have the archives that I downloaded:

```
2MGF&DPNA.part1.rar
2MGF&DPNA.part2.rar
2MGF&DPNA.part3.rar
2MGF&DPNA.part4.rar
2MGF&DPNA.part5.rar
```

Everywhere write that utility `unrar` unpacks automatically a chain of archives.

But when I entered

```
unrar x '2MGF & DPNA.part1.rar'
```

I saw that only one archive was unpacked.

It turns out *I beleive*  the utility does not work as it should, if I unpack after it the second archive manually, then I just have to replace the files!This is not at all what you need!

I need a clear instruction for arch Linux, *I beleive* 7z also does not know how to unpack multi-archives.

Comment: Please do not mince post boobies, since the problem is real

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do not fool me, the question is not only dumb

Comment: @Jackson, peace man! You didn't ask the question on the right place. You should rather try https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please read the links. This questions has nothing to do with programming at all. It is a question about the program `unrar` program and is thus off topic here. I think it would work on Superuser.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you could unpack the first alone, then it means it is independent from the others.

The solution is to extract every archive one by one.

```
unrar x '2MGF&DPNA.part1.rar'
unrar x '2MGF&DPNA.part2.rar'
unrar x '2MGF&DPNA.part3.rar'
unrar x '2MGF&DPNA.part4.rar'
unrar x '2MGF&DPNA.part5.rar'
```

Hope this helps.
J